# If you generate a drop down list with javascript can you still post it in a form

Tags: javascript, php

I have generated a drop down list in javascript for my form. however when i post the form the the values of the drop down list are null.
Even if i select another option from the list, which means it cant be default.
Here is my PHP:

```
    $BirthDays = ($_POST['Days']);
    $BirthMonths = ($_POST['Months']);
    $BirthYears = ($_POST['Years']);
```

And this is the javascript:

```
    function runcalender() {
        var calendar = [
            ["January", 31],
            ["February", 28],
            ["March", 31],
            ["April", 30],
            ["May", 31],
            ["June", 30],
            ["July", 31],
            ["August", 31],
            ["September", 30],
            ["October", 31],
            ["November", 30],
            ["December", 31]
            ],
            cont = document.getElementById('calender');
        //set variables for calender
        var sel_year = document.createElement('select'),
            sel_month = document.createElement('select'),
            sel_day = document.createElement('select');
            sel_year.setAttribute("id", "Years");
            sel_month.setAttribute("id", "Months");
            sel_day.setAttribute("id", "Days");
            sel_year.setAttribute("name", "Years");
            sel_month.setAttribute("name", "Months");
            sel_day.setAttribute("name", "Days");
        function createOption(txt, val) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = val;
            option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
            return option;
        }

        function clearChildren(ele) {
            while (ele.hasChildNodes()) {
                ele.removeChild(ele.lastChild);
            }
        }

        function recalculateDays() {
            var month_index = sel_month.value,
                df = document.createDocumentFragment();
            for (var i = 0, l = calendar[month_index][1]; i < l; i++) {
                df.appendChild(createOption(i + 1, i));
            }
            clearChildren(sel_day);
            sel_day.appendChild(df);
        }

        function generateMonths() {
            var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
            calendar.forEach(function(info, i) {
                df.appendChild(createOption(info[0], i));
            });
            clearChildren(sel_month);
            sel_month.appendChild(df);
        }

        function generateYears(){
            var dateForYear = new Date();
            var x = dateForYear.getFullYear();
            var y = x - 100;
            var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
            for (i = x; i >= y; i--){
                df.appendChild(createOption(i, i));
            }
            clearChildren(sel_year);
            sel_year.appendChild(df);
        }

        sel_month.onchange = recalculateDays;

        generateMonths();
        recalculateDays();
        generateYears();

        cont.appendChild(sel_day);
        cont.appendChild(sel_month);
        cont.appendChild(sel_year);
    }
```

Do i need to get javascript to select the result manually for PHP to recognize it?

Comment: Javascript is client side, PHP is server side.  The only way to get PHP to pick up those values is to do a post.  You will need to assign the select an id (or name, I can't remember exactly which one) for PHP to be able to get the value for it.

Comment: Of course you can post dynamic form field, but did you put these input fields in your form ?

Comment: I've assigned the select with both an id and a name but when i recieve the value via post it is saying that nothing is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean that PHP is receiving the POSTed variables, but the drop down list is not showing the selected result.

If that is the case (and because you are rendering HTML via JS on page load) you need PHP to give information to JavaScript, so that it can show that it is the selected result. I propose the following. Edit the `createOption` function...

```
function createOption(txt, val, isSelected) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = val;
    if(isSelected) option.selected = 'selected'
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
    return option;
}
```

Then write some Javascript to the page that reads the values of the POSTed variables. Your page will need to be *.php for this to work (depending on server configuration)

```
<script language='text/javascript'>
   //Don't forget to sanitize your data, I won't cover that here...
   var postDays = <?php print $_POST['Days']; ?>;
   var postMonths = <?php print $_POST['Months']; ?>;
   var postYears = <?php print $_POST['Years']; ?>;
</script>
```

Finally, when you are running the `createOption` function, give a boolean `isSelected` value (true or false) comparing the value (`createOption()` 'val' param) with the new relevant JS variables... (`postDays` for instance). If the `val` matches `postDays`, give true, if not, give false.

Also, I strongly recommend learning jQuery. You could have probably written the same code block in a quarter of the time. It has a lot of functions to automate what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks mate, id give you a vote but i can't :). Although it would be easier with jquery i would rather learn the full extent of native code....THANKS

Comment: No problem :) I admire your dedication to learning the native code before stepping into frameworks. I found that using jQuery kind-of supercharged how well I understood native code, DOM manipulation, traversing and rendering. It's a little bit intimidating at first (what with the $ everywhere, and initiation of jQuery), but don't be shy! Go on jsFiddle and play with some jQuery examples! Good luck!